# Java is unable to compare ö (Swedish character) from pdfbox

Tags: java, character-encoding, selenium-webdriver, itext, pdfbox

I used pdfbox to get data from a pdf file 
I am comparing that data to the data of webpage using selenium webdriver.
I am able to get data from both.
I used contains method to comparing both data.
Java is able to compare ***glädjande***  type of data but when ***Kommunstyrelsens ordförande*** used as in sentence its not able to match. However ***ordförande*** as a single word can be matched. 
I also tried

```
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper("ISO8859_1");
```

but not able to match data using contains method.

Comment: @Test
  public void TCTwoStringCompare()
  {
   String str1 = "Kommunstyrelsens ordförande Kommunstyrelsens ordförande";
   String str2 = "Kommunstyrelsens ordförande Kommunstyrelsens";
  System.out.println(str1.contains(str2));
  } //This is working

Comment: Have a try and print out the character codes of the two strings. Maybe in one case you don't have an `ö` but instead an `ő`.

Comment: I already used  PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper("ISO-8859-1"); for swedish language. How can I know character code of the string

Comment: `for (char c : string.toCharArray()) System.out.println((int)c);`

Answer (score 1):

Use collater class of java to change the locale & compare the non English strings & characters.

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Locale;

    public class CollatorExp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
        collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);

        if (collator.compare("xéáuér", "xéáuér") == 0) {
            System.out.println("Equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Equal");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: My pdf file is in swedish language. Collator doesnot have Locale.Swedish

Comment: Then I have no idea :(

Comment: :( if java is able to compare the string like "Kommunstyrelsens ordförande " but after getting from a pdf file its not able to compare as a word. I checked with pdfbox and itextpdf also. but same thing is happening !

Comment: @SK See [Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html). Use `new Locale("sv", "SE")`

Comment: It was supposed be there

Comment: Thanks  but I want to compare a substring , not the exact matching of two strings. collator have compare and equal methods not contains method

Comment: I'll suggest you to read this carefully, you will get some idea http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

```
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(local, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
String ascii = normalized.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

By this I am able to ignore ö as o :)

I haven't find how to compare that character but this can be alternative to it